# Why NLTK lemmatization has wrong output even if verb.exc has added right value?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

When I open verb.exc, I can see

```
saw see
```

While I use lemmatization in code

```
>>>print lmtzr.lemmatize('saw', 'v')
saw
```

How can this happen? Do I misunderstand in revising wordNet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**In short**:

It's sort of a strange case of exception.

There's also a case where `I saw the log the into half.` where "saw" is a present tense verb.

See @nschneid solution to use more fine-grain tags in the issue raised: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1196

---

**In long**:

If we take a look at how we call the WordNet lemmatizer in NLTK:

```
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> wnl.lemmatize('saw', pos='v')
'saw'
>>> wnl.lemmatize('saw')
'saw'
```

Specifying the POS tag seems redundant. Let's take a look at the lemmatizer code itself:

```
class WordNetLemmatizer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def lemmatize(self, word, pos=NOUN):
        lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)
        return min(lemmas, key=len) if lemmas else word
```

What it does is it relies on the `_moprhy` property of the wordnet corpus to return possible lemmas.

If we thread through the `nltk.corpus.wordnet` code, we see the `_morphy()` code at  https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1679

The first few lines of the function reads the exception file from wordnet's `verb.exc`, i.e. https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1687

So if we do an ad-hoc search of the exception outside of the lemmatizer function, we do see that `'saw' -> 'see'`:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> exceptions = wn._exception_map['v']
>>> exceptions['saw']
[u'see']
```

So if we call the `_morphy()` function outside of the lemmatizer:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> exceptions = wn._exception_map['v']
>>> wn._morphy('saw', 'v')
['saw', u'see']
```

Let's go back to the return line of the `WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize()` code, we see `return min(lemmas, key=len) if lemmas else word`:

```
def lemmatize(self, word, pos=NOUN):
    lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)
    return min(lemmas, key=len) if lemmas else word
```

So that means the function will return the output from `wn._morphy()` with the minimum length. But in this case both saw and see has the same length so the first on the list returned by `wn._morphy()` will be the returned, i.e. `saw`.

Effectively, the `WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize()` is doing this:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn._morphy('saw', 'v')
['saw', u'see']
>>> min(wn._morphy('saw', 'v'), key=len)
'saw'
```

So the question is:

- **How can I avoid this "bug" in NLTK?**
- **How can one fix this "bug" in NLTK?**

But note that it's not exactly a "bug" but a "feature" to represent other possible lemmas of a surface word (although that word in that specific context is rare, e.g. `I saw the log into half`.

---

**How can I avoid this "bug" in NLTK?**

To avoid this "bug" in NLTK, use `nltk.wordnet._morphy()` instead of `nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize()` that way you will always get a list of possible lemmas instead of the lemma that is filtered by length. To lemmatize:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> exceptions = wn._exception_map['v']
>>> wn._morphy('saw', pos='v')
['saw', 'see']
```

More choice is better than a wrong choice.

---

**How to fix this "bug" in NLTK?**

Other than the `min(lemmas, key=len)` being sub-optimal, the `_morphy()` function is a little inconsistent when dealing with exceptions because of rare meaning in the plural words that might be a lemma by itself, e.g. using `teeth` to refer to dentures, see http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=teeth

```
>>> wn._morphy('teeth', 'n')
['teeth', u'tooth']
>>> wn._morphy('goose', 'n')
['goose']
>>> wn._morphy('geese', 'n')
[u'goose']
```

So the error in lemma choices must have been introduced in the `nltk.wordnet._morphy()` function after the exception list. One quick hack is to immediately return the first instance of the exception list if the input surface word occurs in the exception list, e.g.:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
def _morphy(word, pos):
    exceptions = wn._exception_map[pos]
    if word in exceptions:
        return exceptions[word]

    # Else, continue the rest of the _morphy code.
```

Comment: Thx @alvas, your answer is amazing. I'll check if there are any wrong exception word and reply to you.

Comment: I'm glad the answer helps =)